# most efficient way to create javascript array out of various php arrays

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have a form that a user can submit multiple times, adding different information each time.

These form inputs are translated into php `$_SESSION` arrays, so each time the user hits the submit button, the array grows.  This is working fine.

I need to bring these over into javascript but I'm not sure what the most efficient way is to build the `dataSet` array.

```
dateReceived = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['dateReceived']);?>;
name = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['name ']);?>;
color = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['color ']);?>;
```

Each of these variables will be the same length always (e.g. - the first time the user presses the button their length will all be 1, then it will be 2, etc...), so I need to create an array in javascript that looks like this:

```
dataSet = [
  [dateReceived[0],name[0],color[0]],
  [dateReceived[1],name[1],color[1]],
  etc...
  ];
```

What's the most efficient way to go about this?  I tried using `dateReceived.length` to grow the array over each iteration of the user's button press, but it's just writing the latest set of data and not growing the array:

```
for (i = 0; i < dateReceived.length; i++ ) {
  dataSet = [
    [dateReceived[i],name[i],color[i]],
  ]
}
```

I would love it if someone could help fix the syntax/logic issue in my for loop, but also advise whether not this is an efficient way of doing this in the first place.

Comment: `var dataSet = <?= json_encode($_SESSION); ?>;`

Comment: I would use the [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function in javascript for this one.

Comment: @adeneo while this is definitely more efficient than writing `dateReceived = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['dateReceived']);?>;` for each variable, it still overwrites the data each time, so I'm just getting the last iteration.

Comment: Then you change the loop to work with the new object consisting of the previous arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John,

Try this:

```
var dataSet = [];


  for (i = 0; i < mfrPartNumber.length; i++ ) {
    data = [dateReceived[i],name[i],color[i]];

    dataSet.push(data);

  }
```

This will build an array out of each instance of [i], and keep growing as your user keeps pushing the button.

Comment: looks like you updated your original data - I updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

So you have 3 arrays, all with the same length and consistent indexing. I'll assume that will always be the case.

```
var dataSet = [];
dateReceived.map(function(item, index) {
  dataSet.push([item, color[index], name[index]);
});
```

Now you are appending an array to your dataSet array! Magic!

The problem here is that JS Arrays are pointers and not literal representations of slices in memory. In your loop you are simply overwriting your data.

In addition, JavaScript has a lot of great functional programming utilities (it is arguably a functional programming language) so I would encourage using them when appropriate.

If you need to have this update frequently, you'll want to register an event listener with your front-end code on the 'change' event. BUT this will only work as a one-shot solution. Once you have the initial state set up you'll want to only operate on the new data (otherwise you'll be iterating over an ever-growing array over and over again). In that case you'll want to be keeping track of the last index used or throw away data that hasn't been aggregated so you'll only be operating on the fresh, tasty data.

See: [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
[Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: Thank you so much!  What's the benefit of using the `array.map` function over the answer posted below yours?  As I asked in my question - I want to do this in the most efficient way, (and I want to learn more about using javascript too...) so I will read up on this, definitely.  I'm just wondering if there's a benefit to using this over the other answer since the other answer does work.

Comment: Both of these will work - the only problem is that neither is efficient if you are going to constantly be doing the same operation on these arrays. I updated my answer with some caveats and next steps you might want to take.

Comment: You're right that `in your loop you are simply overwriting your data`.  I overwrite it each time with the same php variable, but the php variable grows because it's a session variable, so if the user clicks the button 5 times, it's overwriting that 1st set of data 5 times, but it's also adding 2/3/4 and 5.  This doesn't feel efficient, but it works.

Comment: Great - thank you so much for your effort answering this.  I really appreciate it and will read up on these additional functions.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your situation, it may be easier to do it server side.  If you are talking about a user form, the number of items will probably be sufficiently low to not make a noticable difference what method you use.  So I personally wouldn't worry about efficiency at this stage.

```
<?php

$date_list = $_SESSION['dateReceived'];
$name_list = $_SESSION['name '];
$color_list = $_SESSION['color '];

$my_data = array();
for ($index = 0; $index < count($date_list); $index++) {
    $my_data[] = array($date_list[$index], $name_list[$index], $color_list[$index]);
}

?>
var dataSet = <?php echo json_encode($my_data, true); ?>
```